# Which is the correct web site to download Moq binary files?

Tags: moq

I want to play around with Moq framework. I wanted to download the framework, so I reached http://code.google.com/p/moq/ through google, but the first line mentions that this project has been moved to GitHub. When I went to GitHub I see only the source code. My questions are :

1) Which is the correct web site to download Moq binaries.? (I do not want Source code.). 
2) Why am I not able to view the binary files in the GitHub website for Moq. Is it that I need to download the source code and then compile it myself.?
3) Should I only go to GitHub website in future for any updates. Currently code.google.com/p/moq provides binary files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The moq project now moved to [github](https://github.com/Moq/moq4). The quickstart is also now on [github](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

So to answer you questions:

1. You can get the latest version from **nuget**: http://nuget.org/packages/Moq/
2. Or download the latest binaries from github: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/releases
3. At the moment you can still download the old moq binaris from the **Downloads** page: https://code.google.com/p/moq/downloads/list (you can use to search filter if you are looking for older versions) or you can use
4. In the future a who knows where it be hosted, because it is an open source project you can create you own fork and maintain it to make sure that it will last until you need it.

Comment: What I do, when in a team and we don't use nuget, is shelf/save the current project/start a new project and download it via nuget. Now that we have the binaries, I keep them aside and undo the whole thing. Now just use the latest binaries as you wish.